# magento 2 split database and use new connection

Tags: database, split, connection, magento2

I have implemented multiple database for my magento2 website. I have total three databases.magento,magento_checkout and magento_quote. I have created my custom module which has custom flat table in setup script.When this module runs, It is creating my table in magento database. I want it to be created in magento_checkout. I want to use connection of checkout database. I try to set argunment in di.xml to use the connection of checkout database but it is not working. can someone help in this?

Answer (score 0):

> Namespace = Exigo
>
> Module name = Flippdf
>
> Database Name = test
>
> username = root
>
> password = root

1) In app/etc/**env.php** add this code:

```
'custom' => array (
              'host' => 'localhost',
              'dbname' => 'test',
              'username' => 'root',
              'password' => 'root',
              'engine' => 'innodb',
              'initStatements' => 'SET NAMES utf8;',
              'active' => '1',
          ),
```

And

```
 'custom' => 
array(
  'connection' => 'custom'
),
```

Final env.php file look like this:

```
  'db' => 
  array (
    'table_prefix' => '',
    'connection' => 
    array (
      'default' => 
      array (
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'dbname' => 'magento2',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => 'root',
        'active' => '1',
      ),
       'custom' => array (
          'host' => 'localhost',
          'dbname' => 'test',
          'username' => 'root',
          'password' => 'root',
          'engine' => 'innodb',
          'initStatements' => 'SET NAMES utf8;',
          'active' => '1',
      ),
    ),
  ),
  'resource' => 
  array (
    'default_setup' => 
    array (
      'connection' => 'default',
    ),
     'custom' => 
    array(
      'connection' => 'custom'
    ),
  ),
```

2) Next step is to configure resource model to use new connection. The di.xml configuration file of module will help to set new resource name to resource model. In Exigo/Flippdf/etc/di.xml add this code:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Exigo\Flippdf\Model\ResourceModel\Flippdf">
        <arguments>
           <argument name="connectionName" xsi:type="string">custom_setup</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

3) Now you can print external database data like this:

> $collection = $this->_modelFlippdfFactory->create();
>
> $item = $collection->getCollection();
>
> print_r($item->getData());

For Example in Controller File:

```
<?php

namespace Exigo\Flippdf\Controller\Index;

use Exigo\Flippdf\Model\FlippdfFactory;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

    protected $resultPageFactory;

    protected $_modelFlippdfFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
         FlippdfFactory $modelFlippdfFactory
    ) {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->_modelFlippdfFactory = $modelFlippdfFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $collection = $this->_modelFlippdfFactory->create();
        $item = $collection->getCollection();

        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($item->getData());// Get test table data from external database
        exit;

        //return $this->resultPageFactory->create();
    }
}
```